# Unable to install Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for alpine based docker

Tags: docker, odbc, alpine-linux, msodbcsql17

I have been trying to install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server for alpine in my dockerfile. I run the following commands in my docker file

Taken from - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#alpine-linux

```
RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7 8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql tools_17.5.1.2-1_amd64.apk


RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.sig
RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.5.1.2-1_amd64.sig

RUN apk add gnupg
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk


RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk
```

However, I get the following message each time. I can see in the run interactive mode that the files are there.

can't open 'msodbcsql_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.sig': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're downloading `msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.sig` and trying to verify `msodbcsql_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.sig`. Double-check the filename as the error message says.